# How can I save the minimum and maximum values from a dynamically changing cell in google spreadsheet?

Tags: google-sheets, max, minimum

There is a cell A1 in which the value changes every second, how to save the minimum value from cell A1 in cell B1, and in cell C1 save the maximum value from cell A1 in google spreadsheet?

Comment: it's working for max, great. but for min it you should use
=MINIFS(A1:B1,A1:B1,">0")

Answer (score 0):

Please try in B1:

```
=min(A1,B1)
```

and in C1:

```
=max(A1,C1)
```

and in File > Spreadsheet settings... > Calculation turn on Iterative calculation with Max. number of iterations set to `1`.

Comment: Doesnt work [Google spreadsheet table link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1I3-1wr3rRNFF_9rLtFxS588_kPKnSgtpPvKnjO-cOFU/edit#gid=0)

Comment: I think for this question i need script

Comment: I want save lowest and highest value from A1